# how would i give a unique identifier to a row in a text file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am currently running a system where the user adds a category of food which is then saved to a text file in my app data. All the categories are listed and there are buttons next to each one.

When the user clicks the button, that food category must be deleted from the text file.

I am using asp.net mvc. I would like to know how I can give each category stored a unique identifier? This is what should be displayed in the text file:

```
1 University,0
2 Groceries,1
```

Comment: Doesn't that work? If the 1 before University is the unique identifier, isn't that enough? Or if it is the value after the comma, wouldn't that work? What is the problem you have with your current solution?

Comment: 1 and 2 itself are unique identifier for row. 1 represents University it means no another value should assign to 1 other than university. Moreover you can also GUID fro unique identifier. Please be more specific to your question.

Comment: thats how it should be but i dont know how to assign the identifier. so when i type groceries in the text box how will i give it an indentifier

Comment: look text box has value and text that's it

Comment: <selection> <item value="1"> sometext</selection> <item value="2"> some text</item></selection>

Comment: giving unique identifier to a text files only thing that I could possibly think of was GUID because it is not incremented and is unique var id = new GUID(); and when you want to call just call the record with matching GUID and in the dropdown even you can use that as value field